# "Multiple locks on web thread" error thrown inconsistently

Tags: objective-c, ios, web, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a strange error in my iOS app.  The error message is as follows:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x22c820: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
```

The odd thing is that it happens inconsistently -- sometimes clicking a certain button or textField will cause the crash, and other times the same steps won't cause a crash.  I originally had a few UIWebViews in one viewController, but I've commented out everything related to them, so as far as I know, I'm not accessing the web thread at all. Even when I did have these UIWebViews in my project, the error often occurred in viewControllers unrelated to the webView.  I also got the error once when my app was open on the device and I received an email.  The push notification from the email seemed related. Any ideas what might be causing this?

I am suspicious that this might be related to the way we are currently segueing between viewControllers. We are using modal segues and manually dismissing one viewController upon loading another. Is that a bad idea?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.